# Big XML file getting weblogic.rjvm.ResponseImpl.unmarshalReturn java.io.EOFException

Tags: java, xml, weblogic, unmarshalling

I am getting following error while passing a xml file to ejb bean in following code
`ejbBean.persistTransaction(new StringBuffer(xml), fileName, 0, 0, null, inboundQueue);`

The issue does not occur for smaller files. The big file gets processed in production environment. Is the issue regarding file size?

Error:

> weblogic.rjvm.PeerGoneException: ; nested exception is: 
>           java.io.EOFException
>           at weblogic.rjvm.ResponseImpl.unmarshalReturn(ResponseImpl.java:234)
>           at weblogic.rmi.cluster.ClusterableRemoteRef.invoke(ClusterableRemoteRef.java:348)
>           at weblogic.rmi.cluster.ClusterableRemoteRef.invoke(ClusterableRemoteRef.java:259)
>           at com.t.integration.common.ejb.server.tradiant_IntConnectMgrHome_37znyp_EOImpl_1035_WLStub.persistTransaction(Unknown Source)
>           at com.t.servlet.ProcessXMLServlet.sendDirectEjb(ProcessXMLServlet.java:357)
>           at com.t.servlet.ProcessXMLServlet.doPost(ProcessXMLServlet.java:282)

Comment: The file size is 20 MB

Comment: You may want to add the code where the exception is being thrown.

Comment: Have you tried taking the file from production and processing it onto your UA or test environment?

Comment: What call is `persistTransaction`... google only returns 500 results. The problem is likely with the api you are using